# Polymorphic routes pointed to same controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, polymorphic-associations

This is a polymorphic association!

```
 resources :professors, :labs do
   member do
     resources :teaching_assistants
   end
 end
```

I want to have index for professors teaching assistants, labs teaching assistants and teaching assistants like so:

```
/professors/id/teaching_assistants
/labs/id/teaching_assistants
/teaching_assistants
```

All these routes are pointing to 
      teaching_assistants#index. Do i have to explicitly point the nested routes to an action in in the professors and labs controller? How would I do that/alter the routes file?

```
 resources :professors, :labs do
   member do
     resources :teaching_assistants, except: :index
   end
 end

get '/professors/id/teaching_assistants' => professors#assistantsindex
get '/labs/id/teaching_assistants' => labs#assistantsindex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *resources* is for creating all the basic RESTful pointers (index/create/read/update/delete). It sounds like your teaching assistants are a 'one off' listing page, in which case you would simply use *get* to create the route.

Try this:

```
resources :professors, :labs do
    member do
         # /professors/id/teaching_assistants > professors#teaching_assistants
         # /labs/id/teaching_assistants > labs#teaching_assistants
         get 'teaching_assistants'  
    end
end

# /teaching_assistants
get 'teaching_assistants'
```